# converting uchar in c++

Tags: c++

How do I convert a uchar to an int?

Comment: It depends on what the `unsigned char` represents, and what you want the `int` to represent. In particular for character codes. Otherwise, if you just want to preserve the value, just assign (note that this has formally undefined behavior when the `unsigned char` is not representable as `int`, which however can only happen on machine with `sizeof(int) == 1`, such as TI signal processor).

Comment: I feel that saying that someone elses question is not real a bit rude and insulting.

Comment: "not a real question" is one of the common reasons for closing a question on SO. you can address the rudeness and insultingness of that on meta chat. what is your solution?

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach:  I would say "there aren't enough details" instead of "not a real question".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `uchar`  is typedef of `unsigned char`, then it's simple:

```
unsigned char c = 'A';
int i = c; //automatic conversion uchar into int!
```

Casting (i.e `int i = (int)c`)  is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char x = '\xff';
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(x) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
255
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply assigning it to a int variable for implicit conversion

```
unsigned char c = 'c';
int i = c;
```

Or explicitly type-casting the variable

```
unsigned char c = 'c';
int i = (int)c;
```

Comment: There is no need for the cast. There is automatic conversion here.

Comment: It is a preference of mine actually (sometimes the compiler feels like optimizing away some stuff), but anyhow edited.

@Nawaz I fail to see how is the cast an overkill. It won't affect the compiled binary to my knowledge although I agree it is a bit tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
void func(int x)
{
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char c = 'c';
    int           t = c;   // auto converts to int

    func(c);   // Works the same (auto converts)
    func(t);   // Or use the t variable.
}
```